# Really confused by Menu Access module in Drupal 6

Tags: routes, users

I have created a new role named 'moderator' to give lower access than main admin to some persons. I have created a specific navigation menu for this role. This role needs to have permission to create menus but I don't want it sees the default drupal main navigation menu.

I searched for this issue and found the 'Menu Access' module to have more control on menus. I installed it but I am really confused by it. I have set create/edit/delete menu and item menu permission for moderator role in permission page.

I also set those permissions in build/menu page. Then I edited default site navigation and unchecked the permission for moderator role. But the moderator still see 'navigation' in the build/menu page.

I use Drupal 6 .

I don't know what the problem is.
Would you help me ?